# How to get all the Id of section tag present under ul tag

Tags: jquery

I am new to Javascript and Jquery so please excuse if this is a dumb question

I have a HTML as shown

```
<div id="restmenu" class="restMenu">
   <ul>
      <section id="Home" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit someclassss">Home<span id="deleteHome" class="inDelete"></span><span class="inEdit" title="Modify Address" name="Modify Address"></span></div>
      </section>
      <section id="Office" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit someclassss">Office<span id="deleteOffice" class="inDelete"></span><span class="inEdit" title="Modify Address" name="Modify Address"></span></div>
      </section>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I was trying this way

```
var existing = $("#restmenu").find('ul').map(function () {
               return $(this).attr("id");
               }).get();
alert(existing);
```

But this produced an empty alert .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

in your code `$("#restmenu").find('ul')` you just find `ul` not `section`

```
var existing = $("#restmenu").find('ul section').map(function () {
               return $(this).attr("id");
               }).get();
alert(existing);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/5/)

Answer (score 0):

One more jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/74axeyud/

```
<div id="restmenu" class="restMenu">
   <ul>
      <section id="Home" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit someclassss">Home<span id="deleteHome" class="inDelete"></span><span class="inEdit" title="Modify Address" name="Modify Address"></span></div>
      </section>
      <section id="Office" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit someclassss">Office<span id="deleteOffice" class="inDelete"></span><span class="inEdit" title="Modify Address" name="Modify Address"></span></div>
      </section>
   </ul>
</div>
<input type="button" value="exec" onclick="getdate()" />.
```

JS is

```
function getdate()
{
    var val = "";
    console.log( $("#restmenu ul"));
    $("#restmenu ul section").each(function( index ) {

      val = val + $(this).attr("id") + " ";
    });    
    alert(val);
}
```